# MDI form VisualStudio error: referenced object and not contain a definition for component

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new in Visual Studio and C#. I am working with a MDI form. (Form1 -> parent; Form2 -> Son)

I am trying to resize a textBoxComponent when formSize changes. So I have next event:

```
private void form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Width = this.Size.Width - 16;
        textBox1.Height = this.Size.Height - 39;
    }
```

And It works fine, but if I put `textBox1.Width = FORM2.Size.Width - 16;` instead of `textBox1.Width = this.Size.Width - 16;` I get next error: `An object reference is required for the non-static 'Form.Size' field, method or property`.

Other thing reffered this is: How could I know which are Form2 borders? (I found out that there are 16 and 39 being tested, but I'm sure there must be some property for this) (Something like `textBox1.Width = Form2.Size.Width - Form2.Size.WIDTHBORDER` instead of `textBox1.Width = Form2.Size.Width - 16`)

Also, when I am on the parent (form1) I wanna call textBox1 (a component declared in form2) like so: `this.ActiveMdiChild.TEXTBOX1.prop` instead of `this.ActiveMdiChild.ActiveControl.prop` (calling his ID, not his ActiveControl) but I get next error: `'Form' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1' nor is there any extension method 'textBox1' that accepts a first argument of the 'Form' type (are some using directive or an assembly reference missing?)`

Thank you all.

Comment: var obj = (Form2)sender;  Use ClientSize instead of Size.

Comment: and similarly, cast `ActiveMdiChild` (it is of type `Form`, so the compiler cannot know it has a `textBox1` member): `((Form1)this.ActiveMdiChild).textBox1.Text`. watch your uppercase/lowercase, identifiers in C# are always case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks you both!!! It solves my problems. I am so grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) answer my question, for solve the first part of my question:

```
ERROR: "An object reference is required for the non-static 'Form.Size' 
field, method or property"
SOLUTION: var obj = (Form2)sender;

ERROR: "Delete form borders"
SOLUTION: 'Use property ClientSize instead of Size'
```

As [dlatikay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132334/dlatikay) answer my question, for solve the second part of my question:

```
ERROR: "'Form' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1' nor is there any 
extension method 'textBox1' that accepts a first argument of the 'Form' type 
(are some using directive or an assembly reference missing?)"
SOLUTION: ((Form1)this.ActiveMdiChild).textBox1
```

Thank you both so much.